# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib._path'

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

While I installed properly the `matplotlib` and `seaborn`. I was able to import `matplotlib` but when I was trying to import the `seaborn` I got the following error message. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib._path'` . Same if I was trying to import `matplotlib.pyplot`.

After spending a lot of time googling and trying this and that, installing and unistaling, finally, I

first checked out the 
`import sys`
`sys.path` to see what are the folders that it searches for the installed packages.

my result was something like this.

`['',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py36',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py36\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py36\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py36\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py36\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py36\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\.ipython']`

then as suggested I import `matplotlib as mpl` and `mpl.__path__` seeing that I import matplotlib from the folder `'C:\\Users\\gsotiropoulos\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages'` Which is not the one from anaconda and it is older. I am not sure if it would be better to just remove this folder completely.

However, as I understand, python first searched there and found a matplotlib package which was outdated. I simply changed the name of the `matplotlib' to something like 'matplotlib_test' and then the library is installed from one of the anaconda folders and the problem is solved.

As I understand I installed in the past python but the 'roaming' folder did not get unistalled. Is that right?
I wonder if I should delete the "roaming" folder to avoid similar other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally started using anaconda and installing everything in one environment. In this way, I save and import everything that I want in this environment without any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution is to add the line sys.path.append(/path/to/located/package).
A permanent solution is to add the path to .bashrc